# Доступ к классу исключения

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Если метод класса из пакета `A` выбрасывает собственное исключение, определённое в пакете `A`, а класс используется в пакете `B`, можно ли делать класс исключения `package private`? `IDEA` показывает, что можно. Но я тогда не смогу его ловить в `B` получается?

Comment: Очевидно нельзя. Отсюда вывод - Если нельзя словить приватное исключение, то и смыла делать приватный класс исключения нет. Используйте тот же Exception|RuntimeException.

Comment: @Sergey у меня и наследуется от `RuntimeException`, а если не надо ловить?

Comment: Если не надо ловить - не ловите. Но если Runtime надо ловить, а его не надо, то даже не знаю. Оно ведь в Runtime и попадётся. Значит тот, кто ловит должен его отличать от других, а для этого надо делать его public

Answer (score 2):

Не получится поймать его в catch, т.к. код просто не скомпилится

```
catch (MyPrivateException e) // error
```

Можно будет поймать его более общим типом

```
catch (Exception e) // MyPrivateException поймается
```

Но если кому-то захочется в обработчике написать разную логику для разных исключений, возникнут проблемы, поэтому лучше так не делать.

```
catch (Exception e) {
    if (e.getClass().getName().contains("MyPrivateException") {
       // единственный способ отличить такое исключение
       handlePrivateException(e);
    } else {
       throw e;
    }
}
```